# nullPointerException when replacing char sequence

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, charsequence

I developed a very simple android app and then I obfuscated the code. A nullPointerException is throwed when, probably, I replace a char sequence.

Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.xpandit.pemobile.android.loadactivity.ak.d(Unknown Source) 
at com.xpandit.pemobile.android.loadactivity.g.onTextChanged(Unknown Source) 
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6335) 
at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6376) 
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6520) 
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889) 
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352) 
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269) 
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432) 
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409) 
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28) 
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583) 
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:174) 
at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120) 
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:257) 
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As i said the code is obfuscated and by the mapping file I've found the right method (at least I think). The question is: In what situation can a replace method throw a null pointer?

Maybe the problem is not the replace method! Can anyone tell me where is the problem and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:**
I think the problem must be on that simple if instruction.

```
if (aux.contains(" ")){
    aux = aux.replace(" ", "%20");                
}
```

Comment: A few questions... Why do you obfuscate code? How shall we help you without the code?

Comment: You should provide code which causes `NullPointerException`.

Comment: if the NullPointerException is really on your code line, then the single explanation is that the variable aux is null.

Comment: From the log it appears the crash is in third party package..

Comment: After a few hours melting my brain I've found the bug... A View's id was missing on the xml. The most weird thing is that I can't understand why the replace method was involved on it!

Answer (score 2):

if this instruction throws NPE

```
if (aux.contains(" "))
```

So it's clear that aux is null, so you can not call contanis method on null. 
Add some check on null state

```
if ( aux!=null && aux.contains(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`

```
if (aux.contains(" ")){
     aux.replaceAll(" ", "%20");                
}
```

Reference:

```
String  replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

Copies this string replacing occurrences of the specified target sequence with another sequence.

```
String  replaceAll(String regularExpression, String replacement)
```

Replaces all matches for regularExpression within this string with the given replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (aux.contains(" ")){
```

throws an NPE if aux is null. It should be

```
if (anx != null && aux.contains(" ")){
```